# How to print custom page size as portrait in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

Below is my code to create custom page size in ItextSharp.
Page is now printing in landscape mode. I want print in Portrait.

```
document = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(410f, 288f));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
document = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(410f, 288f));
```

With:

```
document = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(410f, 288f).Rotate());
```

And the custom page will be rotated by 90 degrees, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Document document = new Document(default(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle));
  document.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(410f, 288f).Rotate());
```

please try this.