# How to print the details in landscape in pdf using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

My requirement is  to print the details in landscape,not the page rotation.i need content printed  in landscape.

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, (float)MarginLeft, (float)MarginRight, (float)MarginTop, (float)MarginBottom);
//210 mm width * 297 mm height
PaperWidthAvailable = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(210f) - ((float)MarginLeft + (float)MarginRight);
PaperHeightAvailable = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(297f) - ((float)MarginTop + (float)MarginBottom);
wdtOFcell = (float)BarcodeWidth + (float)BarcodeSpaceHorizontal;
colNo = (int)Math.Floor(PaperWidthAvailable / wdtOFcell);
TableWidth = wdtOFcell * colNo;
htOFcell = (float)BarcodeHeight + (float)BarcodeSpaceVertical;
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memStream);
doc.Open();
int noOfColumns = colNo;
// int additionalRow = imageBarcodeLists.Count % noOfColumns;
int i = 1;
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(noOfColumns);
table.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
table.TotalWidth = TableWidth;
table.LockedWidth = true;
float[] widths = new float[colNo];
for (int j = 0; j < colNo; j++)
{
    widths[j] = wdtOFcell;
}
table.SetWidths(widths);
iTextSharp.text.Image itextBarcodeImage = null;
foreach (System.Drawing.Image barcodeImage in imageBarcodeLists)
{
    var imageCompressor = new ImageCompressionUtility();
    System.Drawing.Image barcodeImages = imageCompressor.TrimImageWhiteSpacesFromImage(barcodeImage);
    itextBarcodeImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(barcodeImages, BaseColor.BLUE);
    itextBarcodeImage.ScaleAbsolute((float)BarcodeWidth, (float)BarcodeHeight);
    PdfPCell cells = new PdfPCell(itextBarcodeImage);
    cells.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    cells.PaddingTop = 0f;
    cells.PaddingRight = 0f;
    cells.PaddingBottom = 0f;
    cells.PaddingLeft = 0f;
    cells.UseAscender = true;
    cells.FixedHeight = htOFcell;
    cells.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
    cells.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    table.AddCell(cells);
    i++;
}
doc.Add(table);
doc.Close();
```

Comment: Please explain why your question is different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422403

Comment: it rotates  only the paper not the content written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant `iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4` is actually a `Rectangle` that is created like this:

```
public static readonly Rectangle A4 = new Rectangle(595,842);
```

If you want to rotate the page, you can use the `Rotate()` method as explained in my answer to this question: [How to print custom page size as portrait in itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422403/how-to-print-custom-page-size-as-portrait-in-itextsharp)

However, based on your comment "it rotates only the paper not the content written", you may be looking for a page size that is created like this:

```
Rectangle myA4 = new Rectangle(842,595);
Document doc = new Document(myA4);
```

If that doesn't work, please take a look at my answer to the question [iText - Rotate page content while creating PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591689/itext-rotate-page-content-while-creating-pdf)

In that answer, I introduce a page rotation using a page event:

```
public class MyPdfPageEvent : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        writer.AddPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE, PdfPage.SEASCAPE);
    }
}
```

If none of the above has the effect you desire, you should improve your question (or it will be closed as "unclear what is asked").

Comment: and i rotate the cell too.      cell.rotation=180;